# Making tool window show automatically on VS load

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-addins, vsx, vsix

In my Visual Studio extensibility project, I'm attempting to make my tool window visible upon launch after package installation.

The [dotneteers describe a way](http://dotneteers.net/blogs/divedeeper/archive/2009/02/02/LearnVSXNowPart41.aspx) of doing this that involves adding the following line to the package header (i.e. MyPackage.VSPackage.cs):

```
[ProvideToolWindowVisibility(typeof(MyToolWindow), Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.UIContextGuids80.NoSolution)]
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. It seems that Visual Studio doesn't pay attention to the "NoSolution" tool visibility directive (I can confirm that it does work for [some of the other enumeration items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb170698.aspx), like Debugging, but this doesn't fit my use case).

If there's no way to make this auto-show the tool window on VS load, has anyone come up with any alternate (i.e. novel :)) solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, you can try making you package as auto load using ProvideAutoLoad and once at the Initialize() try to create this tool window. Use the Package.FindToolWindow() method.

Comment: Thanks for that! I edited your answer to include some example code, as I needed to tweak when the window show occurred (i.e. only once Visual Studio is fully loaded).

Comment: Ok it seems I'm not supposed to add code to your answer. I can post the code if anyone needs it :)